# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes - как работает plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

t=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
s=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])

def err(k,l,m):
    return sum( k*l + m )

w=np.linspace(1,10,100)
plt.plot(w, err(w,t,s))
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (100,) (4,)

Я ожидаю, что plot станет последовательно перебирать значения w из списка. Но он пытается запихнуть весь список в функцию. И вот тут я мохг поломал :( как обходить-то?

Comment: Неужели минусовать будете?...

Comment: Из вашего кода не совсем понятно что вы считаете и что хотите нарисовать... Что делает функция `err()` - считает __суммарную__ ошибку? Если так, то в решении можно использовать векторизированный подход и обойтись вообще без циклов... [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU да, считает суммарную ошибку. Нарисовать зависимость суммарной ошибки от параметра. А про векторизованный подход, это с использованием типов numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос возможно давно уже не актуален, но всё же напишу вариант, не совсем "векторный", но почти:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

t = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])

def err(k,l,m):
    return (k*l + m).sum()

w = pd.Series(np.linspace(1,10,100))
plt.plot(w, w.map(partial(err, l=t,m=s)));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Суммирование `sum` вызывается не питоновское, а пандовское.
- Датафреймы не нужны, достаточно `Series`.
- Маппинг функции на массив значений сделан через `Series.map` и `functools.partial` - потому что у функции ещё два параметра и их нужно как-то передать.

Можно было сделать через списковые сокращения, `lambda` и т.п., но так всё же более "векторно" получается.

Answer (score 0):

В случае датафреймов (ну и со списками тоже прокатит)
создаем список возвращаемых значений через генератор

```
y = [err(ts, t, s) for ts in w]
```

для списков только требуется переписать функцию

```
sum( k*x + y for x in l for y in m )
```

иначе нарвемся на

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'